# Docker-Compose + postgres: database and user creation not working (works without compose)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, alpine-linux

The [docs for the postgres Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/#environment-variables) explain that you can make the image create a user and database on creation, using environment variables.

I can't seem to make that work using docker-compose:

```
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: iotplatform
      POSTGRES_USER: iotplatform
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: iotplatform
```

and here's what I run:

```
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate postgresql
docker-compose exec postgresql psql -U iotplatform
# psql: FATAL:  role "iotplatform" does not exist
```

When I run `docker-compose exec postgresql env`, I see the environment variables as configured.

The logs don't say anything particular:

```
Attaching to iot-container-tracker_postgresql_1
postgresql_1  | 2018-12-17 17:35:05.754 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgresql_1  | 2018-12-17 17:35:05.754 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgresql_1  | 2018-12-17 17:35:05.757 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgresql_1  | 2018-12-17 17:35:05.770 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-12-17 17:35:03 UTC
postgresql_1  | 2018-12-17 17:35:05.772 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgresql_1  | 2018-12-17 17:35:22.639 UTC [34] FATAL:  role "iotplatform" does not exist
```

---

#### EDIT: tried without docker-compose and it works.

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=iotplatform -e POSTGRES_DB=iotplatform -e POSTGRES_USER=iotplatform -d postgres:alpine
docker exec -it some-postgres psql -U iotplatform
iotplatform=#
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Note that there might be some caching involved, as I first ran the image without any configuration. Is there a harder reset than `--force-recreate` that I should try?

Comment: Hi, I used your docker-compose part and it works well. Which version do you have of docker-compose?

Comment: @StéphaneJeandeaux docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running `down` and `up` it works. Apparently `--force-recreate` wasn't a hard enough reset.

Thanks @StéphaneJeandeaux for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you created your postgres DB before assigning your `POSTGRES_USER` variable meaning the database first got created with the default user ('postgres').

To check if this is the case, when you run `docker-compose up` you will see in the logs something like:

```
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
```

So what you need to do in this instance is remove the volume attached to the container.

i.e.

```
docker-compose down --volumes
```

or `docker volume rm {volume_name}`